# "Imperatively" assign a predefined @callback signature to a function definition?

Tags: jsdoc

If I have a function signature defined either in JSDoc with `@callback` or in a .t.ds library using `type`, can I somehow use JSDoc to "attach" that signature to multiple function definitions?

```js
/**
 * @callback ruleDefiner
 * @param {RuleDefinitionBuilder} builder
 */
```

Then:

```js
/** @thisFunctionIsA {ruleDefiner} */
function spellfix(builder) {

    // The IDE should know that builder is a RuleDefinitionBuilder
    const {depends, produces, cmd, T} = builder;

    const input = depends("foo.txt");
    const output = produces("foo.spellfixed.txt");
    cmd(T`spellfix ${input} > ${output}`);
}

/** @thisFunctionIsA {ruleDefiner} */
function sign(builder) {

    // The IDE should know that builder is a RuleDefinitionBuilder
    const {depends, produces, cmd, T} = builder;

    const input = depends("foo.spellfixed.txt");
    const output = produces("foo.signed.txt");
    cmd(T`sign ${input} > ${output}`);
}
```

What should I use instead of pseudo-JSDoc `@thisFunctionIsA`?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can, using the `@type` tag.

```js
/**
 * @callback ruleDefiner
 * @param {RuleDefinitionBuilder} builder
 */

/** @type {ruleDefiner} */
function spellfix(builder) {

    // The IDE should know that builder is a RuleDefinitionBuilder
    const {depends, produces, cmd, T} = builder;

    const input = depends("foo.txt");
    const output = produces("foo.spellfixed.txt");
    cmd(T`spellfix ${input} > ${output}`);
}

/** @type {ruleDefiner} */
function sign(builder) {

    // The IDE should know that builder is a RuleDefinitionBuilder
    const {depends, produces, cmd, T} = builder;

    const input = depends("foo.spellfixed.txt");
    const output = produces("foo.signed.txt");
    cmd(T`sign ${input} > ${output}`);
}
```

**EDIT:**
If this is truly/strictly for JSDoc, see [this JSDoc documentation](https://jsdoc.app/tags-type.html) for more. However, if you, like me, only use JSDoc with JavaScript for IntelliSense in your editor, you probably want [this TypeScript documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsdoc-supported-types.html) (which JavaScript IntelliSense is actually using) instead.

Comment: At least in JetBrains IDEs, using `@type` does not work like you think it does. It simply specifies the return type for the function. I have reported it as a bug, but it seems that the report fell into a limbo, and I got neither a confirmation that this is indeed a bug (only that they could reproduce it, which isn't the same as admitting it's a bug), nor did they say it's by design and I should use a different syntax.

Comment: I am basically trying to get intellisense for a JS-based DSL, where the DSL files cannot import the DSL types or classes. A DSL file can only default-export an entrypoint function that receives an object through which all work is done, and I need the IDE to know that object's type. There are other nested occurrences of this pattern, with functions that take several parameters.

Comment: As I don't have experience with JetBrains (I use VSC), I can only speculate then as to how to handle that. `@type` is in no way meant to specify return type, certainly not in JSDoc or TypeScript. If the issue is truly with `@type` and not something else, there's only so much you can do I think, but I have a couple ideas:

Comment: Shooting in the dark, maybe the issue lies more with `@callback` instead, and you might be able to instead replace your whole function definition with `/** @typedef {(builder: RuleDefinitionBuilder) => any } ruleDefiner */` and then use `@type {ruleDefiner}` as expected.

Comment: In fact `ruleDefiner` is now defined in .t.ds, but I previously had the same issue with `@callback`. I basically ported the "scripting host" to TS, but "user scripts" must remain in JS.

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, then your issue may actually be just a lack of reference. Within your `index.d.ts` file, you can instead have `export type ruleDefiner = (builder: RuleDefinitionBuilder) => any;` (note that this is actual TS, *not* a JSDoc comment, but it won't affect runtime, it should strictly work for your IDE, but I think based on your comment you know this). Then, within your actual `index.js` file, you can instead use type as `/** @type {import('.').ruleDefiner} */` which will bring your `.d.ts` file into scope for the IntelliSense in your JS file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231227/discussion-between-user3781737-and-szczepan-holyszewski).